# Googlemap Not visible in Vf Page

Tags: visualforce, google-map

I have used the below code and it is worked fine while runing as HTMl file. But if I used with the Visualforce page. the map not visible.

Map not showing please look the below image.

**Googlemap code source:**

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/directions-draggable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to give a fixed height to your `map-canvas`.

```
<div id="map-canvas" style="float:left;width:70%; height:800px"></div>
```

instead of

```
<div id="map-canvas" style="float:left;width:70%; height:100%"></div>
```

And your map will be displayed !

Comment: Yes Thank lot. It is working fine. I have doubt. Why the corner side showing my personal gmail icon. google map only visible, if we have the gmail account form the end user side. look this link to show the image. http://prntscr.com/64ikf4

Comment: If you don't want your gmail icon showing, you have to change the JS script you're using : `<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&signed_in=true"></script>` -> just remove `signed_in=true`

Comment: Can we find the location based on the phone number?